# UITextInputTraits.returnKeyType not working in keyboard extension?

Tags: ios, uikit, swift4, custom-keyboard

So I am developing an iOS keyboard extension and I want my return button text to change according to `returnKeyType`, however, it seems this API is not working properly on keyboard extension.

I have a hosting app with some UITextField and when I use built-in English keyboard, its return key correctly changed based on the `returnKeyType` I set for the UITextField.

But for my own keyboard extension, I run a debugger and I always see

```
self.textDocumentProxy.returnKeyType = .default
```

My logic is very simple, I have this func to change return text

```
public func changeReturnText() {
    var text: String
    let returnKeyType = self.textDocumentProxy.returnKeyType
    SpeedLog.log("Return Key Type: \(returnKeyType?.rawValue ?? -1)")
    switch returnKeyType ?? .default {
    case .continue:
        text = "繼續"
    case .done:
        text = "完成"
    case .go, .google, .yahoo:
        text = "前往"
    case .search:
        text = "搜尋"
    case .next:
        text = "下一個"
    case .send:
        text = "送出"
    default:
        text = "換行"
    }
    returnKey.text = text
}
```

Then I put that func in my `init()`

I was able to run debugger against this, but that `self.textDocumentProxy.returnKeyType` always returns `.default` even if I set the UITextField `returnKeyType` to `.done` while built-in English keyboard works just fine.

Any idea? Much appreciated.

Comment: You say you put it in your initializer, so my guess is that the system hasn't actually sent you the latest state for the textDocumentProxy. You should probably call this function whenever you get an update like textDidChange.

Comment: @BenPious You are absolutely right! Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks and I’ll have a try in my debugging app. I did it in viewdidloaded and it seems too early.

Answer (score 1):

As Ben Pious pointed out, apparently I was calling `textDocumentProxy` too early. And noted that `textDocumentProxy` is only available after the frame is non-zero.